# If we must take the train to the place, we will have to wake up early that day. - "Should" in if-clause to mean "have to"?

Tags: modal-verbs, conditionals, future-constructions

**Example 1**

> If we have to take the train to the place, we will have to wake up early that day.

**Example 2**

> If we must take the train to the place, we will have to wake up early that day.

**Example 3**

> If we **should** take the train to the place, we will have to wake up early that day.

Do they all have the same meaning?

I have learned from a source that "should" in an if-clause means possibility. However, I do not know if it has a different meaning here or conveys the same meaning as in Example 1 and 2 here.

Comment: I think #3 is ambiguous, in that it *could* mean *If we **ought to** take the train...* OR *If **it so happens that** we take the train...* But I suggest it's better for learners to avoid ***should*** wherever possible, so I certainly *don't* think #3 above should be endorsed.

Answer (score 3):

No, they don't.

**If we should** [do something] means "If it so happens that we do it", not "if we are obliged to do it".

> If you should see John, will you give him my regards?

Answer (score 2):

> Should in an if-clause means possibility

This is a different use of "should." This is along the lines of "If I should die before I wake," which means basically "If I *were to* die before I wake." It's a conditional. It's also rather antiquated. Knowing about this usage would help you understand if you encounter it in older material, but I would be unlikely to use it today.

However, it's a generalization to say that "*should* in an *if*-clause always has this meaning." It's unlikely but possible to imagine a realistic situation in which it means "ought to":

> "It's almost time for dinner! You should be setting the table!"
> "*If I should* be setting the table, who should be stirring the risotto?"

But this is very contrived; the only reason it works is that the second person is essentially quoting the first person's more standard usage.

Answer (score 0):

In your last example, it's better to use something like "need to" because whether you take the train or not is up to you. You either take it or not. It doesn't happen by chance.
However, you can use "should" in an if-clause **if there's a possibility for something to happen by chance**.

Example:
If you should have a problem like this again, you can come and talk to me.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine 'pairings' like this:

- would : will ...certainty
- could : can  ...capability
- might : may  ...possibility
- should : shall ...obligatory (but not as dogmatic as 'must')

The 'should' obligation might be legal, moral, social, environmental, etc. or something 'fuzzier' like custom, etiquette, convenience etc.

'I should phone my sister today' (social/moral?)

'I should take the train, not the car' (ecological/financial?)

'I should hold my fork in my left hand' (regional custom/etiquette?)

In my interpretation, your example:
'If we should take the train...' implies an obligation of some sort to do so ...but not everyone meets all their obligations!

If you are not trying to convey obligation, your use (in my interpretation) is ...archaic? ...poetic?
Nothing wrong with such use, but it may not convey your intended message as clearly as you wish.

If your intended message is about a conditional obligation:
'If we must take the train...' eliminates archaic/poetic interpretations.
Otherwise, if your intended message is purely speculative:
'If we take the train...' does the job simply and unambiguously.

ChrisM